# Mostrar los 3 resultados mas cercanos o futuro de la fecha actual Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo podría hacer una consulta asi en mysql?

> Quiero que muestre 3 resultados iguales o futuro desde la fecha actual ordenados desde la mas actual

Como es un sistema en donde se suben datos de planificacion futura necesito que solo muestre los mas cercanos a la fecha actual

```
SELECT a.id_actividad, a.nombre_actividad, 
               a.fecha_actividad
FROM actividades as a
WHERE a.fecha_actividad BETWEEN NOW() 
and    ??? resultados>= a la fecha actual
ORDER by a.fecha_actividad DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: que muestre fechas mayores o iguales a la fecha actual?

Comment: Si, un ejemplo hay 4 registros, 2 con la fecha de hoy 20, uno de mañana 21 y uno de pasado mañana 22. El query desde hoy muestre 20,20,21, mañana 21,22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hago uso de `DATE()` para extraer de los registros solo la parte de *fecha* y descartar las horas, minutos y segundos *solo para el proceso de consulta*

Construye tu consulta del modo siguiente:

- En el `WHERE` establecemos que la fecha registrada sea igual a la fecha actual con `NOW()`
- Para poder establecer que obtenga también el registro del día siguiente, hacemos una condición con el operador `OR` en la cual indicamos la misma comparación anterior, pero también hacemos uso de `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` para indicarle que a la fecha actual le sume un día mas

**Códido SQL adaptado**

```
SELECT a.id_actividad, a.nombre_actividad, a.fecha_actividad
FROM actividades as a
WHERE DATE(a.fecha_actividad) = DATE(NOW())
OR DATE(a.fecha_actividad) = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER by a.fecha_actividad DESC LIMIT 3
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- [Ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86db85d2890d17b6a8c3f34f3345c006)
- [Función `DATE()` en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: Pero eso sólo mostraría las 3 primeras actividades entre hoy y mañana.  Si el día de hoy no hay actividades, y mañana sólo hay 1, entonces las otras 2 debería tomarlas de pasado mañana en adelante.  Así como está no lo haría.

Comment: Eso lo comprendo @JohanDonadoB. sin embargo al momento de dar esta respuesta, traté de apegarme a lo comentado por el OP en la zona de comentarios, igual es bueno recibir observaciones y aportes de otros

Answer (score 0):

Como está en la respuesta anterior sólo tendría en cuenta las actividades de dos días, hoy y mañana, pero no siempre van a estar las tres actividades entre hoy y mañana;  es posible que hoy haya una actividad y mañana otra, entonces la tercera actividad debería tomarla de pasado mañana o los días siguientes.

Creo que lo correcto sería:

```
SELECT a.id_actividad, a.nombre_actividad, a.fecha_actividad
FROM actividades as a
WHERE DATE(a.fecha_actividad) >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER by a.fecha_actividad DESC LIMIT 3
```